# Mercurial push and pull between two remote repositories

Tags: mercurial

Is it possible to push from one remote repository to another remote repository?

I have a case where I push my local changes to a remote integration repos. Once approved, I want the integration repos pushed into a release repos (where I'll build my release from).

Is this technically possible?

EDIT: 1st repository is local on my disk. 2nd and 3rd are both remote repositories on my server that I DON'T have file system access to. I want to be able to push from 2nd to 3rd from my PC (using my local HG/TortoisHG client).

Comment: Why don't you push from the 2nd to the 3rd repository?

Comment: Because he doesn't have access to the server on which the second repository resides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple way is to login to your server, `cd` to the integration repository and then push to a release repository.

If you do not have such a login, simply keep a local clone of the integration repository which you *only* use to locally push to a remote release repo:

```
$ hg clone <remote-integration-repo> integration
$ cd integration
$ hg push <remote-release-repo>
```

For subsequent pushes, do

```
$ cd integration
$ hg pull # optionally with -u option
$ hg push <remote-release-repo>
```

In case you have multiple integration and release repostitories, you might want to automate these steps in a script.

The basic message is that it does not really make a difference if you push to the release repo from a local or remote machine.

Comment: Just to add a note - I cannot login directly to my server, but I realize that push from remote to remote is not possible, so I will use the option suggested of pulling 1st repos to a local repos and pushing from it to the 2nd remote one.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by "remote". If you can log into these machines and you can establish an SSH connection between them, it's easily possible.

Comment: As I added in my EDIT - I can't access the file system on the machine with the remote repositories.